# "git submodules update --recursive" doesn't seem to go into sub-submodules

Tags: git, branch, git-branch, git-submodules

I have a project that's consisted of two branches: STABLE and DEVELOPMENT. As the names suggested, DEVELOPMENT is the ever-ongoing developing branch and STABLE is the stable-but-not-so-new branch; hence the versions of submodules (and sub-submodules) in DEVELOPMENT are often ahead of STABLE.

Now, whenever I need to checkout from DEVELOPMENT to STABLE, **git submodules update --recursive** will not get into these "sub-submodules" at all and their directory will simply become empty, while all the submodules will be properly shunted back to an older version if needed. I have no idea how to get this right and would appreciate some helps.

Comment: What is the output of `git --version`?

Comment: what is your command sequence? It sounds to me as if the STABLE branch either doesn't have the sub-modules, or they have content that exports somewhere else, hence leaving the named directories empty (git doesn't delete empty directories)

Comment: Just checking Git Community book http://book.git-scm.com/5_submodules.html which gives "Pulling down the submodules is a two-step process. First run `git submodule init` to add the submodule repository URLs to .git/config.  Now use `git-submodule update` to clone the repositories and check out the commits specified in the superproject"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer myself:

`git submodule update --init --recursive` is a neat one-line command to do the job.